# YouTube_it Gem Bad Authentication

Tags: ruby, youtube-api

I am using Youtube_it and used this example https://github.com/chebyte/youtube_it_rails_app_example. However I keep getting the error BadAuthentication. This would lead me to believe that my user, pass or dev_key is wrong but I have checked many times.

Is there anything else that can cause this?

Comment: I have the same problem. I have opened an issue in https://github.com/kylejginavan/youtube_it/issues/208

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Heroku even though my local application had no issues.

Turns out Google blocks unauthorised account accesses from unknown sources.  I had a notification pop up on my Gmail account and I simply followed the instructions to resolve the issue.

Comment: could you please include the link with the instructions

Comment: It was literally a notification that appeared in my Gmail inbox.